# CSS changes does not affect on normal browser magento 2 issue

Tags: magento2, cache

I have made some css changes in my website, like hidden "Add to cart" option from everywhere on the website. This css gets only affected in incognito mode and not visible on normal browser. Customer visit the store in normal browser only. What can i do so that css changes are visible on normal browser also.

Answer (score 0):

did you recreate static files and cleaned the cache?